# What are the advantages and disadvantages of pretty printing JSON?

Tags: json, pretty-print, json-ld

Pretty printing JSON will tend to make it heavier than those rendered without pretty print. Beyond that I can't think else of something between pretty printing or not.

Let's say you want to provide web services for a public RESTful Web API, will it affect server performance, round-trip time, etc.?

So again, what are the advantages and disadvantages of pretty printing JSON?

Comment: It's for the benefit of the human reader... not much else.

Comment: Just an improved readablility.

Comment: too many correct answers

Comment: Sad to see that the picture was gone, I really liked the old question :-)

Comment: Pretty-printing is for human consumption, machines don't need it. I know only one case where it could actively hurt, and that is logfiles that are intended to be human-readable but sometimes also machine-readable. If one log entry spans multiple lines, processing it can become more difficult. This is not specific to JSON though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advantages**

1. Easier to read

**Disadvantages**

1. The size of the data will increase
2. There will be some computational overhead

Thinking about this for all of 4 more seconds, I can't add any more to those lists! :P

Answer (score 2):

Tools can both versions just the same, but the pretty printed versions are more readable for humans.

Why doesn't everyone pretty print?

For the same reason people don't turn on their car lights during the day, even though it would improve their visibility:

- People don't think about it: `json.dump()` works, move on to the next problem.
- It's not the default, so it takes a tiny bit of manual work
- People don't see it as something they should optimize for.
- People tend to micro-optimize other things (JSON string size, car battery usage)